# How to read automatically-created variants

Tags: abap

I need to read automatically-created variants, to get the selection screen parameters and other selection criteria. The names of such variants begin with symbol `&` (for example, `&0000000000425`). Such variants are created once you schedule any background job from `se80`/`se38` or any transaction without choosing any existing variant (from the selection screen, menu Program -> Execute in background).

The function module `RS_VARIANT_CONTENTS` works fine for normal variants (which can be seen via `se80`/`se38`), but not for the automatically-created ones (that begin with `&`). I looked into the FM and found that the `VARI` table was read by the next code:

```
IMPORT %_VARI40C   TO P_VARI
     %_VARI40    TO L_VARI_40
     %_VARI      TO L_VARI
     %_VARIVDAT  TO P_VARIVDAT
*         %_VARIDYN40 TO P_VARIDYN
     %_VARIVDAT_DYN40 TO P_VDATDYN
     DYNS_FIELDS TO OLD_DYNSFIELDS
     DYNS_TEXPRI TO OLD_TEXPRI
     DYNS_EXPR   TO OLD_EXPR
     DYNS_FIELD_TAB TO DYNS_FIELDS
     DYNS_TEXPR TO DYN_SEL-TEXPR
         FROM DATABASE VARI(VB) CLIENT L_CLIENT ID P_RKEY
         ignoring structure boundaries
         IGNORING CONVERSION ERRORS.
```

However the import returns nothing for the `&` variants. It looks like the values for `&` variants are stored within a format which is different from the format used by FM `RS_VARIANT_CONTENTS`.

Is there any way to find a proper format/data structure for & variants values?

Update: I created `ZBC_TEST` program and scheduled it as a job. I see a record in `VARI` table:

```
MANDT    RELID   REPORT     VARIANT         SRTF2
200      VB      ZBC_TEST   &0000000000425  0
```

So, the `&0000000000425` variant exists in `VARI` table. `VARI-CLUSTD` field is not empty for the record. I use this code:

```
CALL FUNCTION 'RS_VARIANT_CONTENTS'
  EXPORTING
    REPORT        = 'ZBC_TEST'
    VARIANT       = '&0000000000425'
    MOVE_OR_WRITE = 'W'
  IMPORTING 
    SP            = lv_sp
  TABLES
    VALUTAB       = lt_valtab.
```

The FM has been performed without any exception and `sy-subrc=0`, but `lt_valtab` table is empty...

Comment: I can read the variants without problems using the function module - what did you try exactly? Also be aware that these variants are deleted automatically by the job scheduler - maybe that is part of your problem?

Comment: Please see an update in my question above.

Comment: I can not reproduce that behavior. Are sou sure that ZBC_TEST has either PARAMETERS or SELECT-OPTIONS...?

Comment: Sorry, this is a my fault. ZBC_TEST has neither screen parameters nor select-options. I checked RS_VARIANT_CONTENTS with other report and the FM works fine. Thank you for this!

Comment: @Skalozub please convert your comment into an answer, because "Stack Overflow has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions" (cf [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function module is working correctly: Since your program does not have any parameters, the returned value set is empty.